# Include html to DOM in memory to avoid redraw

Tags: jquery, dom, load, redraw

I write this function with jQuery to load pieces of html's into another:

```
function xInclude() {
    var includes = $('[include]');
    if (includes.length == 0)
        return;

    includes.each(function() {
        var obj = $(this), url = obj.attr('include'); 
        obj.load(url, function() {
            obj.removeAttr('include');
            xInclude();
        });
    });
};
```

Then I use it like this:

```
<div include="my-extra-content.html">

<script>
    xInclude();
</script>
```

It works well, but how can I make all changes to the DOM in memory to avoid redraw?

Comment: You question is not clear, what do you mean by 'redraw' and 'in memory'? Do you mean the delay caused by the AJAX request?

Comment: Unrelated, but you could shorten your code to just `$('[include]').each`. It won't do anything if the length is 0.

Comment: Each DOM changes means that the browser should do redraw the entire contents. I want to make the changes in memory to avoid that. I know is possible but I'm not sure how.